# What does the amplitude mean in Matlab plots for PID controllers

Tags: matlab, control-theory

In the PID design tool of Matlab, the results from different gain values can be shown in a plot. The x-axis in such a plot is time while the y-axis is amplitude. What is the definition of this amplitude? You can find an example of such a figure in the following document.

http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/~sc4070/transp/refresher.pdf

And the amplitude results should depend on the reference input or setpoint, but how to set the reference input or its function of time in the Matlab pid tool?

Answer (score 0):

If your target system transfer is y(t)/u(t), that plot is in units(y)

[image]

---

If your Control Device has a transfer function

```
G(s)=Y(s)/U(s)
```

The transfer function of your closed loop Y(s)/Sp(s) will be

```
H(s)=K(s)G(s)/(1+K(s)G(s))
```

With K(s) the transfer function of a PID

```
K(s)= Kp + 1/(Ki s) + Kd s
```

All these functions are in Lapace space.

To calculate the system output to an input `sp(t)`(the setpoint).

```
L^-1 ( Sp(s)H(s) )
```

where `L^-1`  is the inverse lapace transform.

Or you do what every other moral does, Use a math toolbox (Matlab/Simulink, Octave) to solve the System response numerically.

Use a symbolic math toolbox to have an analytical expression that probably won't tell you nothing.

Comment: so it has nothing to do with the reference input or set point value?

Comment: your setpoint and input_error  are in  `y` units too. if your setpoint is constant, and there are artefacts, the error will be 0, so not much to see there.

Comment: sorry, where I said *artefacts* should have said *no artefacts*

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what the amplitude value is and how it is calculated.

Comment: It's a plot of y(t), when set_point(t) is a step function. The plot represents the evolution from one stationary state to another. If your control device is a system (resitor heater + Room ), y(t) would be Room_temperature, U(t) would be current applied to the heater, SET_POINT is your target temperature. The plot of y(t) is the evolution of the room temperature after changing the SET_POINT

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer. I understand what the amplitude is now, but I still feel confused. I do not see any function of set_point(t) in the Matlab commands. The input to the step() command in Matlab is the system model instead of the reference input values. There must be a reference input but where?

Comment: `step()` shows the response of a system to an unitary step, that means set_point is 0 for t<0, 1 for t>=0, you can validate the input by plotting the trivial system `step(tf(2,1))` (output will be 2)

Answer (score 0):

That's just matlab telling you what the signal type is. In a control system, the units are difficult to make sense. The step function works also for open loop systems so it doesn't have to be a set point to output plot. The interpretation that you have only makes sense for closed loop systems.

For example you can have a cruise control system where the set point is velocity and the actuator is the gas throttle pedal degree. Now if you plot this you have to label the y-axis **km/h per degree** which is pretty a nonsensical unit.

Moreover, matlab model doesn't know what the units are if you don't supply that information. Hence instead of label-less plot it just says *this is the amplitude of the output signal resulting from supplying a step input*. Nothing more.

I would suggest right-clicking the step plot and choosing `Normalize` to get a ratio of the input and the output to get rid of the confusion.